# Fullcalendar: Dropdown HTML within Resource hidden by Calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, resources, dropdown, html-injections

I'm trying to add specific actions within a dropdown to the given fullcalendar resources. So far Fullcalendar is a very great tool, but somehow the calendar overlaps the HTML content that I'm injecting.

Is there a better way to inject Dropdowns and other HTML elements, without being overlapped by the calendar?

It would be great if the dropdown would be completely visible. Am I missing something?

[image]

```
resourceGroupLabelDidMount: function(e) {
  var $this = $(e.el);
  $this.find('.fc-datagrid-cell-cushion').html($('.element').html())
}
```

Here is a code example: https://codepen.io/sirsir1/pen/BaYXqVj

Comment: Have you tried giving the dropdown and its cells a bigger z-index? Can't quite see if you're using a standard `<select>` there or some custom plugin, either, so that might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson ! Yes, I already tried with the z-index without any luck. The css also contains already a high z-index. It's a common bootstrap dropdown `ul` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my own question, it seems to work fine by adding `position-fixed` class to the `ul` element:

```
<ul class="position-fixed">
  ...
</ul>
```

Here is a working code example: https://codepen.io/sirsir1/pen/zYWdPRN